# HOW TO - SQL join to combine output from 2 tables based on 1 common table mapping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables

```
UserRights - This table contains extra role selected for the user has been defined. 
RoleRights - Default roles defined by the users
UserRole - To map the user and their default role
Roles - Role name (ID = Primary Key)
```

CONDITION: User has to be part of a ROLE, only then they can select extra roles if required.

```
| UserRights |
|---------------|
| UserID (FK)   |
```

```
| RoleRights    |
|---------------|
| RoleID (FK)   |
```

```
| UserRole      |
|---------------|
| UserID (FK)   |
| RoleID (FK)   |
```

Now, consider if the **RoleRights** has been defined with 37 rows for a specific role and **UserRight** table has 1 row defined by the user for a specific user. The mapping table which is **UserRole** has the definition which maps USERID and the ROLEID.

We need to construct the output which result in 38 rows, i.e. take 37 rows from =**RoleRights** table and 1 row from **UserRights** table based on UserID.

How do we go about constructing SQL query to result this output?

Comment: Do you want to get the rights records only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to do it with `UNION` because it allows you to write 2 independet queries.

```
select UR.UserRightID 
from UserRights UR 
where UR.UserID = @UserID

union

select RR.RoleRightID 
from RoleRights RR
where exists 
    (select * from UserRole UR1 where UR1.RoleID = RR.RoleID and UR1.UserID = @UserID)
```

You can use `UNION ALL` of you want to get all records even if they have the same value from both queries.

Comment: I have additional common columns (add and query executes correctly) and we export to XML. While doing this, I get column name is repeated and cannot generate XML file. How to handle this? I am in no position to change out application code.

Comment: The columns in both queries have to have the same type and the count of columns needs to be the same. This is all that is reuquired by UNION. Exporting to XML is a different problem, I'm guessing. You should probably ask a separate question.